# Not able to access the facebook api with php

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am not able access facebook api with php it throws error when I use `require src/facbook.php`
or `include src/facecbook.php`:

```
facebook needs curl extension for php
```

I added `php_curl` file and make entry in `php.ini`. But no use. Can any one help to resolve the issue. Please give detailed explanation.

Comment: Show us some code..how should we help you with that information you gave us?

Comment: My question is quite obvious, but have you tested cURL installation? Does it work?

Comment: yes , I enable the cURL.But it isn't help me.

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension." The code is                       require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).




$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '344617158898614',
  'secret' => '6dc8ac871858b34798bc2488200e503d',
));

Comment: As shown above I am not able to connect to facebook php sdk. Can any body have solution to this error.

Comment: Delete your comment above with your App secret in it and reset this in your app toolbar. This is not information you should EVER share publicly.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like cURL is installed on your server. Create a php file with just this and run it:

```
<?php
echo 'cURL is '.(function_exists('curl_init') ?: ' not').' enabled';
```

If it says "cURL is not enabled", then you need to install it. Contact your hosting provider, or if you're rolling your own server [read this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php).

If you're using a free host, most of these disable cURL and all of the `file` functions in php for security.

Comment: Thanks Cpilko for your reply. I got the message "cURL is not enabled" while using your echo statement.Even though I enabled it on php.ini file using "extension=php_curl.dll" . Can you help how to do funcion_exist(curl_init) is enabled in above echo statement.  Please guide me to enabled cURL on the server[apche].

Comment: You need to install cURL through your PHP install. See the link in my original reply for directions about how to install this in your PHP installation.

Comment: I installed the php_curl and included the extension in php.ini file.    Currently I am using winamp PHP 5.3.13 and I checked with 5.2.17 php version. I enable the curl file. But not workinng the "echo 'cURL is '.(function_exists('curl_init') ?: ' not').' enabled';" showing message curl not anabled. Can any one help in detail manner as I am facing this issue "Facebook needs CURL PHP extension" from past one month.

Comment: Can any body help on this I am facing this issue " facebook needs curl PHP extension " while tring to connect to facebook php sdk.

Comment: 1., make sure you edited the _right_ php.ini. 2., use `phpinfo()` to check (after server restart), that cURL is enabled. (There should be a whole section headlined `curl` in the phpinfo output. And you can also see the path to the actually used php.ini file at the very top.)